# Auto answer message box

Tags: vba

I am writing a short script compiling other macros.
It allows me to run three macros at once if I want to, rather than each one one by one.
I don't want to have the reply to the message boxes in the other 3 macros. The default answer is fine.
I am using the  `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` method. Here:

```
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Application.Run "Mod_Patients.MettreDatesAJourPatients"
        Application.Run "Mod_Prescripteurs.MettreDatesAJourPrescripteurs"
        Application.Run "Mod_Services.MettreDatesAJourServices"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "Data has been updated"
```

Only that the `Application.DisplayAlerts` false/true does not work.
The subsequent message boxes appear.
I can't find a workaround.

Comment: You would have to modify the code in each macro to remove the MsgBox lines as they are not the same thing as Alerts.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `Application.Run` if the macros are in the same workbook.

Comment: In addition to what @braX noted, if you want to those message boxes to appear in the case the macro is run on an individual basis but not when you run them together, you can pass an optional argument to display the msgbox or not. (You'll still need to modify each macro to pass this argument and have it call msgbox if there).

Comment: Thanks guys...
I had to seperate each single macro into two, with the 2nd one being the one with a message box encapsulating the 1st one. I hence am able to run each macro with or without message now.
Pain, but effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what Scott is suggesting:

```
Sub MettreDatesAJourPatients(Optional WarnUser as Boolean = True)
    '....
    '....
    If WarnUser Then Msgbox "Something something..."
    '....
End Sub
```

When called with no arguments `WarnUser` will be True: if you want to suppress any messages then call with:

```
MettreDatesAJourPatients False
```